# Ruby - keys of one hash into values of another hash

Tags: ruby, hash

I have to hashes like so:

```
hash1 = {
   "a" => 1,
   "b" => 1,
   "c" => 1,
   "d" => 1
}

hash2 = {
  "1" => 1,
  "2" => 1,
  "3" => 1,
  "4" => 1
}
```

And I need to merge them so I end up with this:

```
hash1 = {
  "a" => "1",
  "b" => "2",
  "c" => "3",
  "d" => "4"
}
```

But I don't know where to begin.  Help appreciated.

Comment: on what condition you are merging?

Comment: I'll make a wild guess at what you are looking for: `hash1.keys.zip(hash2.keys).to_h #=> {"a"=>"1", "b"=>"2", "c"=>"3", "d"=>"4"}`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can try the following:

```
Hash[hash1.keys.zip(hash2.keys)]
```

*At first*, you get array of keys for each hash with `hash1.keys` and `hash2.keys`:

```
["a", "b", "c", "d"]
["1", "2", "3", "4"]
```

*Secondly*, you create an array of arrays with `hash1.keys.zip(hash2.keys)`:

```
[["a", "1"], ["b", "2"], ["c", "3"], ["d", "4"]]
```

*Then* with `Hash[<...>]` you create a `Hash` where the first value from the first inner array goes as key and the second as value:

```
{"a"=>"1", "b"=>"2", "c"=>"3", "d"=>"4"}
```

[**Example**](https://eval.in/285339)