# transform values of yaml hash into keys of json hash in Ansible

Tags: json, ansible, yaml, ansible-facts, jmespath

I'm trying to get Ansible to convert an array of hashes, into to a list of key value pairs with the keys being one of the values from the first hash and the values being a different value from the first hash.

An example will help.

I want to convert :-

```
TASK [k8s_cluster : Cluster create | debug result of private ec2_vpc_subnet_facts] ***
ok: [localhost] => {
    "result": {
        "subnets": [
            {
                "availability_zone": "eu-west-1c", 
                "subnet_id": "subnet-cccccccc", 
            }, 
            {
                "availability_zone": "eu-west-1a", 
                "subnet_id": "subnet-aaaaaaaa", 
            }, 
            {
                "availability_zone": "eu-west-1b", 
                "subnet_id": "subnet-bbbbbbbb", 
            }
        ]
    }
}
```

into

```
eu-west-1a: subnet-aaaaaaaa   
eu-west-1b: subnet-bbbbbbbb    
eu-west-1c: subnet-cccccccc
```

I've tried `result.subnets | map('subnet.availability_zone': 'subnets.subnet_id')` (which doesn't work at all) and `json_query('subnets[*].subnet_id'` which simply pickes out the subnet_id values and puts them into a list.

I think I could do this with Zip and Hash [in Ruby](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28511878/ruby-keys-of-one-hash-into-values-of-another-hash) but I don't know how to make this work in Ansible, or more specifically in [Jmespath](http://jmespath.org/specification.html).

Answer (score 1):

I have generated the below list I will add a new line to the generated list(thought to share this first)

```
---
- name: play
  hosts: localhost
  tasks:
    - name: play
      include_vars: vars.yml

    - name: debug
      debug:
        msg: "{% for each in subnets %}{{ each.availability_zone }}:{{ each.subnet_id  }}{% raw %},{% endraw %}{% endfor %}"
```

output --->

```
ok: [localhost] => {
    "msg": "eu-west-1c:subnet-cccccccc,eu-west-1a:subnet-aaaaaaaa,eu-west-1b:subnet-bbbbbbbb,"
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Jmespath does not allow to use dynamic names in multi select hashes. I have found [an extension to jmespath](https://github.com/grofers/go-codon/wiki/Jmespath-extensions#5-support-for--expressions-as-key-when-performing-multi-select-hash) allowing to do such thing by using key references, but it is not part of the plain jmespath implementation nor ansible.

To do this in plain ansible, you will have to create a new variable and populate it with a loop. There might be other ways using other filters but this is the solution I came up with:

```
- name: Create the expected hash
  set_fact:
    my_hash: >-
      {{
        my_hash
        | default({})
        | combine({ item.availability_zone: item.subnet_id })
      }}
  loop: "{{ subnets }}"

- name: Print result
  debug:
    var: my_hash
```